# Filter product collection by custom attribute

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, collection

I'm filtering a product collection by the custom attribute `ean` with the following code

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('ean');
$collection->addFieldToFilter('ean', '678678');

foreach ($collection as $product)
{
     Mage::Log('product found');
}
```

There is product with this ean but no product is found.

Comment: What was the problem? I don't think it was the addFieldToFilter, was it?

Comment: Actually I had a space in at the end of the ean. Remember to always but quotes around debug messages...

Comment: narf :-) Always the same...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The methods `addFieldToFilter()` and `addAttributeToFilter()` are the same.

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php:339
/**
 * Wrapper for compatibility with Varien_Data_Collection_Db
 *
 * @param mixed $attribute
 * @param mixed $condition
 */
public function addFieldToFilter($attribute, $condition = null)
{
    return $this->addAttributeToFilter($attribute, $condition);
}
```

I would try to remove the filter, then loop over the collection and check the values of ean. What query is fired?

Maybe some observer hooks into  `catalog_product_collection_load_before` and the query is altered and filters are added?

Load the collection and then check `echo (string)$collection->getSelect()`. After(!) the `->load()`.

Answer (score 7):

try and use

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('ean', '678678');
```

[This post](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento) gives some nice pointers on using collections

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('ean', '678678');
```

should be:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('ean', '678678');
```