# filter product collection by a comma-separated attribute

Tags: filter, product-collection, magento-1.4

this post gives me a good idea of the basic approach of filters:

[Filter product collection by custom attribute](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7860/filter-product-collection-by-custom-attribute)

However, products have a custom attribute that is actually going to be stored as a multiselect element (which I assume is treated as an array):

```
$product->setAttribute('schoolid','11,12,13,18'); //the schoolid attribute for a given product
//or perhaps it's stored as an array
$product->setAttribute('schoolid', array(11,12,13,13));
```

this needs to be compared against a user's value so a this won't really work:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('schoolid', '13');
```

as this is more of an array comparison.  Is there a standardized way to do this in Magento?  Is there any way in other words to convert the product attribute to an array and do an in-array comparison within the existing model?

Comment: explain more whats u wants and why minus rate.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your `school ids` to array and then apply the filter.

```
$schoolid = '11,12,13,18'; //the schoolid attribute for a given product
$schoolIds = explode(',', $schoolid);

$collection
    //->addFieldToFilter('schoolid', '13');
    ->addFieldToFilter('schoolid', array('in' => $schoolIds));
```

This should do the trick for you.

**UPDATE**

If `schoolid` is a attribute type then filter collection like this:

```
$collection
    //->addFieldToFilter('schoolid', '13');
    ->addAttributeToFilter('schoolid', array('in' => $schoolIds));
```

Comment: This is interesting, why down vote?

Answer (score -1):

```
addAttributeToFilter() is used to filter EAV collections.

addFieldToFilter() is used to filter Non-EAV collections.
```

http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/addattributetofilter/

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

**n - in**

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('schoolid',array("in"=>array('11', '12', '13','18')))
```

**Not In - nin**

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('schoolid',array("nin"=>array('11', '12', '13','18')))
```